# CakePHP delete using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

```
in index.ctp my code is as follows :-
<?php
            foreach( $teacher as $teachers )
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$teachers['Teacher']['username']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$teachers['Teacher']['dgen']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$teachers['Teacher']['dqual']."</td>";                  

                <?php
                echo "<td>".$this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete',$teachers['Teacher']['id']), null, __('Are you sure you want to delete %s?', $teachers['Teacher']['id']))."</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
```

mycontroller code:-

```
 public function delete() 
    {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->layout = 'ajax';
        $id = $_GET['id'];          
        $this->loadModel('Teacher');
        $this->Teacher->delete($id);
        //$this->Session->setFlash('The post with id: '.$id.' has been deleted.');
        //$this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
    }
```

Ajax call :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('a.deleteajax').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var answer = confirm("Delete this record?")
        if (answer){
            $.ajax({
                url:'/Teachers/TeachersController/delete/',
                type:'GET',
                data: $(this).attr("href")
            });
        }
        return false;  
        });
    </script>
```

please help me ... i want delete records without refresh page.

Comment: where is the ajax call you are trying to make.First try to write something and if it does not work then only ask.

Comment: sry... i had problem in posting my ajax code is in iindex.ctp as follws :-

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   $('a.deleteajax').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var answer = confirm("Delete this record?")
   if (answer){
    $.ajax({
     url:'/Teachers/TeachersController/delete/',
     type:'GET',
     data: $(this).attr("href")
    });
   }
   return false;  
   });
  </script>

Comment: This ajax url looks really odd to me... It shoud be: `/teachers/delete` if your controller name is `TeachersController`. But you should really go through docs first, because you are making some really strange things in your delete action like loading a model to controller with `loadModel`. Read the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change ajax to this:Add `id` as key in `data` to access it in your controller.better add success part for confirmation msg of action.

```
$.ajax({
             url:'/Teachers/TeachersController/delete/',
                type:'GET',
                data: {id:$(this).attr("href")},
                success:function(resp){//reso is msg string returned from controller.
                    alert(resp);
                  }

            });
```

Comment: @HarshalBorse are you able to get id in php part.

Comment: but deleting is not performed. ajax is not calling . i tried to put alert(); so as to check but not working.

Comment: @HarshalBorse try  `$this->Teacher->delete(5);` without  loadModel.

Comment: or try raw query like this:`$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$db->rawQuery("DELETE FROM table WHERE id=$id");`

Comment: nothing is happening .. link is working like '#' only.

Comment: i am new in cakephp .. so please tell me how to call the ajax . and in which file i should put it.

Comment: @HarshalBorse it should be in your view.

Comment: so i put the ajax code in index.ctp .. but not calling even i tried to show the alert() in it. can u please give me short code that will call alert() onclick button .. after that i wil make further code.

Comment: read this and try to understand:http://code.runnable.com/UfurM57qFgxsAAAa/simple-ajax-cakephp-time-example-for-sessions  and  http://www.devdungeon.com/content/ajax-form-submit-cakephp-2x

Answer (score 0):

Let give you a solution step by step

At first in your index.ctp

You can apply this code

```
foreach( $teacher as $teachers )
{
          echo "<tr id='echo $teachers['Teacher']['id'];'>";  //used id for daynamic tr, for hide temporary your delete data.

          echo "<td>".$teachers['Teacher']['username']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$teachers['Teacher']['dgen']."</td>";
          echo "<td>".$teachers['Teacher']['dqual']."</td>";                  
          echo $this->html->link('','#',
          array(
               'class'=>'del btn btn-sm btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
               'id'=>$teachers['Teacher']['id']  //important 
          )); 

          echo "</tr>";
}
```

Then If you use jquery ajax get method you can use below code.

```
$('.del').click(function(){
                    var x=$(this).attr("id");
                    jQuery.get("<?php echo  Router::url(array('controller'=>'teachers','action'=>'delete'));?>",               {"id":x},
   function(data,stat){

                    jQuery('#'+x).remove();
     });
});
```

According to your controller code you can add this like below code

```
public function delete($id=NUll) {
    $id=$_GET['id'];     // it's not a good practices you can use $this->request->data/param I mean cakephp syntax.  
    $this->Teacher->id = $id;  
    if ($this->Teacher->delete()) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been deleted.'));
    }
    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
```

This code should work fine.